# How to use a test that is a "substring" of another?

Tags: webpack

I want to do something like this:

```
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.scss$/,
            loader: "style!css!autoprefixer!sass"
        }, {
            test: /\.raw.scss$/,
            loader: "css!autoprefixer!sass"
        }
```

in context:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: path.join(srcPath, "app/core/bootstrap.ts"),
    output: {
        path: wwwPath,
        filename: "app-[hash:6].js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.scss$/,
            loader: "style!css!autoprefixer!sass"
        }, {
            test: /\.raw.scss$/,
            loader: "css!autoprefixer!sass"
        }, ...
]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ["", ".js", ".json", ".scss", ".raw.scss", ".html", ".ts"],
        root: [
            srcPath,
            path.join(__dirname, "node_modules")
        ],
        moduleDirectories: [...]
    },
    plugins: [...]
};
```

Notice how on files that match `.raw.scss`, both loader sets will be run, since `*.raw.scss` also matches the `.scss` test.

What's the right way to implement something like this?  Must I do something gross like change the first `.scss` test to also include a negative lookbehind (not match anything that includes `.raw` right before `.scss`)?

Comment: I'm not even sure if a negative lookbehind is possible with webpack - these don't appear to be true regexes - if they were, the `.` would need to be escaped, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to use `exclude`? ([Docs](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#module-loaders))

```
module: {
    loaders: [{
        test: /\.scss$/,
        exclude: /\.raw.scss$/,
        loader: "style!css!autoprefixer!sass"
    }, {
        test: /\.raw.scss$/,
        loader: "css!autoprefixer!sass"
    }]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What happens if you change the order, so that raw.scss comes first?

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: Webpack executes loaders that match any test (e.g. possibly more than one). :/  Thanks for the good idea, though, and welcome to Stack Overflow! :)